# $this->filter in controller - where is it set

Tags: php, phalcon

I have searched the classes `\Phalcon\Mvc\Controller` & `\Phalcon\DI\Injectable`, but cannot understand where the `filter` attribute comes from.

If in the controller I use

```
$this->filter
```

where does it come from? The interfaces do not reflect this attribute anywhere.

Thanks

Related to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303141/controllers-attr-this-filter-where-from) which was unfortunately closed due to the original poster's English.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303141/controllers-attr-this-filter-where-from

the same question,but my question ......

Comment: Yes I copied it and provided an answer since your question was locked. I thought it would be a good reply for people to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Phalcon Dependency Injection (`\Phalcon\DI`) container, services are registered and interact with one another.

The `\Phalcon\Mvc\Controller` automatically allows access to the services registered in the DI container with the use of magic methods.

So imagine you have registered a `filter` service in your DI container:

```
$di->set(
    'filter',
    function () 
    {
        return new \Phalcon\Filter();
    }
}
```

This service is now available in your controller with the following ways:

```
$filter = $this->filter;
```

or

```
$filter = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('filter');
```

The same goes for anything that has been stored in the DI container.